# Can we break debugger in F12 tool?

Tags: ie

Is there a way in IE developer tool to break the debugger from the middle of execution? I google it, but didn't found any article which give me some direction on this.

Answer (score 1):

Another Method would be to write "debugger" into your JavaScript Code, Open the Debugging Tools (F12) and open your page.

[image]

The debugger will stop where you write "debugger" in your javascript code.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

Open Developer Tools (F12). Add Breakpoint on your desired page. For Example, in this answer I use the AllItem.aspx page.
[image]

Now refresh the page and you will see that the breakpoint was hit.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, But seems my question wasn't clear. Once the debugger starts and if I am in the middle of debugging and if I want to STOP the debugger. How to do it? We have this facility in Visual studio but I wonder, if its there in IE or Chrome.

Comment: If you want to stop the debugger, just click the green Play button. Then the debugger will stop and the page will load normally.

Comment: Any how, green button will execute the execution further (F5). Which I don't want. I am expecting that it should stop it completely and break out. Same like in Visual Studio (Shift + F5)

Comment: anybody knows this?